# How to compare num of text type in elasticseach

Tags: elasticsearch

My Index has a property which is text type , but this property is nums actually,e.g "44564" "4567".
My question is how can compare this property? like "44564" > "4567"

Comment: Could you clarify as how you intend to use this comparison? Like do you intend to use that comparison for like filter purposes at querying time like show documents where 44564 > 4567 or are you looking for sorting based on that property which is text type with numeric behaviour?

Comment: Yes, I want to use this comparison for filter query

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for can be achieved via `painless` script to. You can read more about them [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html).

I have created a sample index with mapping having fields `name` and `postcode`.

The `query` I have created will list people with name `John` who are in the `postcode` area having `postcode` greater than `30500`

### Mapping:

```
{
  "testindex": {
    "mappings": {
      "mydocuments": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text"                
          },
          "postcode": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents

```
POST testindex/mydocuments/1
{
  "postcode": "30005",
  "name": "John"
}

POST testindex/mydocuments/2
{
  "postcode": "31000",
  "name": "John Doe"
}

POST testindex/mydocuments/3
{
  "postcode": "32000",
  "name": "John Wright"
}
```

### Query using painless scripting

In the below query you can make use of `postcode` instead of `postcode.keyword`, however you need to set `"fieldata": true` for `postcode` which is of type text.

```
POST testindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": { 
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name": "john"
        }
      },
        "filter": {
          "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "inline" : "Integer.parseInt(doc['postcode.keyword'].value) > params.param1",
                        "lang"   : "painless",
                        "params" : {
                            "param1" : 30500
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }

    }
  }
}
```

What the above `query` does, is simply converting the `text` into `integer` at query execution time and thereby computes the filter logic.

Notice how for every document, it will parse text into Integer and thereby execute the query. It is pretty evident that query performance would take a nice hit if you eventually have millions of documents.

I would advise you to change the mapping of postcode having its type as `integer` and execute filtering feature accordingly. However, if you don't have a choice and/or consuming 3rd party data, I hope the above query would suffice.

Comment: @T.Arthur No problem. Do please accept the answer if you think it solved your problem.